# europecv and biblatex compatibility problem

Tags: biblatex, templates, incompatibility

I use the `europecv` class and I'd like to use my `biblatex` bibliographies inside. It turns out that `europecv` needs the `ucs` package which is incompatible.

Any idea how to deal with this problem?

Comment: neither the biblatex nor the europecv manual do offer a solution

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `scrlfile` package (part of `KOMA-Script`) features, among other things, a `\PreventPackageFromLoading` macro that does exactly what its name suggests. You may use it to prevent the `ucs` and `inputenc` packages being loaded by `europecv`. After the class is loaded, we redefine its internal command `\ecv@utf` so that `utf8` *really* means `utf8`, lift the ban on package loading and issue `\usepackage[uft8]{inputenc}`.

```
\RequirePackage{scrlfile}

\PreventPackageFromLoading{ucs,inputenc}

\documentclass{europecv}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\ecv@utf[1]{{\inputencoding{utf8}#1}}
\makeatother

\ResetPreventPackageFromLoading

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```