# Cancel the loading of mathpazo after classicthesis

Tags: macros, classicthesis, mathpazo, computer-modern

Is there a way to cancel the loading of this line, in `classicthesis`, after `classicthesis`? To have all the fonts in `CM` like default?

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{osf,sc}{mathpazo}
\RequirePackage{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.05}
```

---

I have tried this way:

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{hfoldsty}% I also would the oldstyle numbers that in standard CM there aren't
\linespread{1}
```

but for example `\mathbb` and `!` still remain in palatino...

### Update:

```
\renewcommand\graffito@setup{%
   \itshape\footnotesize%   \slshape --> \itshape
   \parindent=0pt \lineskip=0pt \lineskiplimit=0pt %
   \tolerance=2000 \hyphenpenalty=300 \exhyphenpenalty=300%
   \doublehyphendemerits=100000%
   \finalhyphendemerits=\doublehyphendemerits}
```

Comment: Try (before loading `classicthesis`, and maybe before loading your document class) `\RequirePackage{scrlfile}\PreventPackageFromLoading{mathpazo}`. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76297/europecv-and-biblatex-compatibility-problem

Comment: `classicthesis` is quite rigid: take or leave. Trying to customize it is a lost battle.

Comment: `hfoldsty` and `lmodern` are contradictory to each other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{scrlfile}
\PreventPackageFromLoading{mathpazo}
\usepackage[pdfspacing,eulerchapternumbers]{classicthesis}

% Latin Modern with oldstyle digits    
\usepackage[% 
  rm={oldstyle,proportional},% 
  sf={oldstyle,proportional},% 
  tt={oldstyle=false,proportional=false,monowidth}% 
]{cfr-lm} 

% \mathbb
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\def\myaddress{http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagina_principale}
%\chapter[test]{\href{\noexpand\myaddress}{\spacedallcaps{test}}}
\chapter[test]{\href{\noexpand\myaddress}{test}}

This is a test for the font used. Here is $\mathbb{Z}$ and here
are the digits 1234567890 in text mode and in math mode $1234567890$.

\sffamily

Here are the digits 1234567890 in text mode (sans serif)

\ttfamily

Here are the digits 1234567890 in text mode (typewriter)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's the list of used fonts from the log file

```
</usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/euler/eurb10.pfb>
</usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmcsc10.pfb>
</usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmr10.pfb>
</usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmss10.pfb>
</usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmtt10.pfb>
</usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/symbols/msbm10.pfb>
```

and from `pdffonts`

```
name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
KNQMFR+LMRoman10-Regular             Type 1            yes yes no      14  0
GNBFRC+LMRomanCaps10-Regular         Type 1            yes yes no      15  0
GNBFRC+LMRomanCaps10-Regular         Type 1            yes yes no      16  0
KNQMFR+LMRoman10-Regular             Type 1            yes yes no      17  0
PWNBSJ+EURB10                        Type 1            yes yes no      28  0
AICAWW+MSBM10                        Type 1            yes yes no      29  0
KNQMFR+LMRoman10-Regular             Type 1            yes yes no      30  0
CTWEBZ+LMSans10-Regular              Type 1            yes yes no      31  0
CTWEBZ+LMSans10-Regular              Type 1            yes yes no      32  0
AUGYQG+LMMono10-Regular              Type 1            yes yes no      33  0
```

If you don't want chapter numbers in the Euler font, remove the `eulerchapternumbers` option and issue

```
\renewcommand{\chapterNumber}{\normalfont\fontsize{70}{70}\selectfont}
```

after loading `classicthesis`; this will use Latin Modern also for the chapter numbers (modify to suit).

Comment: I have also added the code in my updated question to have the compatibility also for the notes in cm. Is it a good idea?

Comment: @FormlessCloud What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: the real meaning of this question is to provide all the codes that allow the full compatibility of the CM with classicthesis. So also this little update have to do with the meaning of the question, also if the title (you are right) seem to indicate a different question.

Comment: @FormlessCloud `graffito` *does* use Latin Modern fonts with my code, but of course with slanted shape. In other words, this has *nothing* to do with the question.

Comment: @FormlessCloud A simple way to change the font to italic is to say, in your document preamble: `\usepackage{etoolbox}\makeatletter\patchcmd{\graffito@setup}{\slshape}{\itshape{}{}\makeatother`

Comment: The scrlfile package isn't already loaded by the KOMA classes? Is there a reason to load it again?